# How to build Firesheep on Mac? 'sys/types.h' file not found

Tags: gcc, build

I'm having problems building this; has anyone got any ideas as to where to find this file / which library to install?

**make**

```
Making all in backend
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile clang -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"Firesheep\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"firesheep\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"Firesheep\ 0.1\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"eric@codebutler.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"http://codebutler.github.com/firesheep\" -DPACKAGE=\"firesheep\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_BOOST=1 -DHAVE_BOOST_FORMAT_HPP=1 -DHAVE_BOOST_ALGORITHM_STRING_HPP=1 -I. -I deps/ -I deps/http-parser -I deps/json_spirit    -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -g -O0 -DPLATFORM_OSX -arch i386 -arch x86_64   -MT libfiresheep_la-http_parser.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libfiresheep_la-http_parser.Tpo -c -o libfiresheep_la-http_parser.lo `test -f 'deps/http-parser/http_parser.c' || echo './'`deps/http-parser/http_parser.c
libtool: compile:  clang -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"Firesheep\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"firesheep\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"Firesheep 0.1\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"eric@codebutler.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"http://codebutler.github.com/firesheep\" -DPACKAGE=\"firesheep\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_BOOST=1 -DHAVE_BOOST_FORMAT_HPP=1 -DHAVE_BOOST_ALGORITHM_STRING_HPP=1 -I. -I deps/ -I deps/http-parser -I deps/json_spirit -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -g -O0 -DPLATFORM_OSX -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -MT libfiresheep_la-http_parser.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libfiresheep_la-http_parser.Tpo -c deps/http-parser/http_parser.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/libfiresheep_la-http_parser.o
In file included from deps/http-parser/http_parser.c:21:
deps/http-parser/http_parser.h:28:10: fatal error: 'sys/types.h' file not found
#include <sys/types.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [libfiresheep_la-http_parser.lo] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

**gcc --version** produces:

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)
```

**/usr/bin/sw_vers**

ProductName:    Mac OS X

ProductVersion: 10.7.3

BuildVersion:   11D2001

Comment: The build is using clang not gcc - so that version is needed

Comment: Did you `./configure` firesheep before `make`ing? Mac OSX 10.7 comes with `<sys/types.h`> already, it's located in `/usr/include/sys/types.h`.

Comment: Clang - that makes sense. I was so focused on error that haven't notices gcc / clang issue. Types.h are in the specified location. Right now my job is to figure out how to set includes / makefiles / etc... Any hints?


`clang --version
Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
Thread model: posix`

Comment: I actually posted message to more specialized forum: http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-May/021152.html

_(thank you very much for suggestions and pointing out this **clang** not gcc)_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue has been solved by **giblfiz** on [github](https://github.com/codebutler/firesheep/issues/169#issuecomment-6985466):

> change the CFLAGS def in configure.ac

```
CFLAGS = -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I was trying to install the database interface (DBI) modules for Perl on my Mac (OSX 10.8). XCode version 4.4 places the header files at `/Developer-3.2.6/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include` instead of `/usr/local/include`. The makefile generated by the perl script was looking at `/usr/local/include` for the header files. After I updated the makefile with the new location, the installation was successful.

Here's the updated excerpt from the makefile:

`CCFLAGS = -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -I/Developer-3.2.6/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include`

Here's the actual command during the installation.

> clang -c   -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN
>   -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector **-I/Developer-3.2.6/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include** -Os   -DVERSION=\"1.622\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.622\"  "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -W
>   -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wno-comment -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-cast-qual -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-unused-parameter DBI.c

Comment: Thanks for effort. Notification from comment reminded me that this issue has been solved already - see my answer below/above.