# When I was installing DBD:mysql for perl, an error came out

Tags: mysql, perl

I want to learn perl, and set up a Mysql database in my little Mac. I tried to install `DBD:mysql`, an error came when I type `make`.

```
In file included from /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/DBIXS.h:23:
/System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/perl.h:610:11: fatal error: 'sys/types.h'
      file not found
#       include <sys/types.h>
```

I tried to googling it for days and no goals, please help me.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure, but maybe you are lack of C-compiler?

Comment: Could you tell me how can I check if I am lack of C-compiler?

Comment: `gcc -v` should tell you what version of GCC you are using

Comment: When I type gcc -v, it response that I have installed gcc 4.2.1, it is weird..

Comment: Well, it's not. It seems your compiler installation doesn't not include `sys/types.h`. Or some Mac things I don't understand are invloved.

Comment: Shall I re-install perl, which is pre-installed in my Mac ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12239211/176646) to a similar question may be of use.

Comment: +1 to @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, that question is not about building Perl, otherwise I would vote this as a duplicate, but it's the same issue of sys/types.h not found on a Mac.

Comment: @BillKarwin Should I close this question coz it is duplicate? I am new here.

Comment: I think the question deserves an answer. If that other answer solves the issue for you, you could write up what you did, and accept your own answer. It's good to leave useful info for the next people who search for the same error. :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin I will edit those useful info later.This is a lovely community.

Answer (score 1):

Typically `<sys/types.h>` means `/usr/include/sys/types.h`.

If your system has '`locate`' installed, you could try

```
 $ locate types.h
```

and see what it says.

Otherwise something like:

```
 $ find / -name 'types.h' -print | less
```

might take a while to run.  But will show you where files named types.h live.

If sys/types.h lives in a non-standard place, you can set CFLAGS environment variable [per the link that @ThisSuitIsBlackNot posted above] to tell the compiler to look in additional directories when searching for include files.