# C Compile Error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, gcc

I'm trying to compile a program on Mac OSX Catalina, and I'm running into the following error:

```
[USER:~/Seisan/PRO]$make all
cd ../LIB; /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make all; cd ../PRO
-------------------------------------------------
---- COMPILING SEISAN LIBRARIES -----------------
-------------------------------------------------
gcc -m64 -c -I../INC -I/usr/X11R6/include -g -o xlib.o xlib.c 
gcc: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘19.2.0
In file included from xlib.c:44:0:
/usr/X11R6/include/X11/Xlib.h:38:23: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [xlib.o] Error 1
--------------------------------------------------
---- COMPILING SEISAN PROGRAMS -------------------
--------------------------------------------------
make: *** No rule to make target `../LIB/./seisan.a', needed by `afadsei'.  Stop.
```

When I run `which gcc`, I get `/usr/local/bin/gcc`.  I have updated Xcode by doing: `xcode-select --install`.  I have XQuartz installed.  What could be the issue?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365645/how-to-build-firesheep-on-mac-sys-types-h-file-not-found

Comment: Thanks, where would the configure.ac file be located?